# How to I configure my own GraphDatabaseService and GraphAwareRuntime in a spring unit test with boot 2.0 and Neo4j SDN5

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j-4, graphaware

I'm writing some unit tests and want to use TimeTree along with Spring repositories, to auto attach event nodes to a time tree. Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30285178/neo4j-timetree-in-spring-data-neo4j-4-0) issue, but I'm using boot 2.0 and SDN5. I think my main issue is I don't know how to set up the configuration so my repositories and my TimeTree use the same GraphDatabaseService. My @Confuration is like this:

```
    @Configuration
    public class SpringConfig {

        @Bean
        public SessionFactory sessionFactory() {
            // with domain entity base package(s)
            return new SessionFactory(configuration(), "org.neo4j.boot.test.domain");
        }

        @Bean
        public org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration configuration() {
            return new org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration.Builder()
                .uri("bolt://localhost")
                .build();
        }

        @Bean
        public Session getSession() {
            return sessionFactory().openSession();
        }

        @Bean
        public GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService() {
            return new GraphDatabaseFactory()
                .newEmbeddedDatabase(new File("/tmp/graphDb"));
        }

        @Bean
        public GraphAwareRuntime graphAwareRuntime() {
            GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService = graphDatabaseService();
            GraphAwareRuntime runtime = GraphAwareRuntimeFactory
                .createRuntime(graphDatabaseService);

            runtime.registerModule(new TimeTreeModule("timetree",
                TimeTreeConfiguration
                    .defaultConfiguration()
                    .withAutoAttach(true)
                    .with(new NodeInclusionPolicy() {
                        @Override
                        public Iterable<Node> getAll(GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService) {
                            return null;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean include(Node node) {
                            return node.hasLabel(Label.label("User"));
                        }
                    })
                    .withRelationshipType(RelationshipType.withName("CREATED_ON"))
                    .withTimeZone(DateTimeZone.forTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+1")))
                    .withTimestampProperty("createdOn")
                    .withResolution(Resolution.DAY)
    //                      .withCustomTimeTreeRootProperty("timeTreeName")
                    .withResolution(Resolution.HOUR), graphDatabaseService));
            runtime.start();
            return runtime;
        }
    }
```

And my test looks like this:

```
    User user = new User("Michal");
    user.setCreatedOn(1431937636995l);
    userRepository.save(user);

    GraphUnit.assertSameGraph(graphDb, "CREATE (u:User {name:'Michal', createdOn:1431937636995})," +
            "(root:TimeTreeRoot)," +
            "(root)-[:FIRST]->(year:Year {value:2015})," +
            "(root)-[:CHILD]->(year)," +
            "(root)-[:LAST]->(year)," +
            "(year)-[:FIRST]->(month:Month {value:5})," +
            "(year)-[:CHILD]->(month)," +
            "(year)-[:LAST]->(month)," +
            "(month)-[:FIRST]->(day:Day {value:18})," +
            "(month)-[:CHILD]->(day)," +
            "(month)-[:LAST]->(day)," +
            "(day)<-[:CREATED_ON]-(u)"
    );

    GraphUnit.printGraph(graphDb);
    graphDb.shutdown();
```

There's a host of errors, but I think they all stem from this one:

```
Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to 
instantiate [org.springframework.data.repository.support.Repositories]: 
Factory method 'repositories' threw exception; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error 
creating bean with name 'userRepository': Unsatisfied dependency 
expressed through method 'setSession' parameter 0; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No 
qualifying bean of type 'org.neo4j.ogm.session.Session' available: 
expected single matching bean but found 2: getSession,
org.springframework.data.neo4j.transaction.SharedSessionCreator#0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the configuration class redefines some beans already automatically configured by Spring boot (here the `Session`).

So spring injection does not know how to choose between the 2.
Removing the `getSession()` should help.

A second thing is that your `SessionFactory` has to use the embedded DB  setup in the `graphDatabaseService()` method. For this, configure an embedded driver with the existing database.

Summary config that should work fine for you :

```
@Bean
public SessionFactory sessionFactory() {
    EmbeddedDriver driver = new EmbeddedDriver(graphDatabaseService());
    return new SessionFactory(driver, "org.neo4j.boot.test.domain");
}

@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    return new Neo4jTransactionManager(sessionFactory());
}

@Bean
public GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService() {
    return new TestGraphDatabaseFactory().newImpermanentDatabaseBuilder().newGraphDatabase();
}

@Bean
public GraphAwareRuntime graphAwareRuntime() {
    ...
```

Comment: Many thanks, looks like I'm back in business. Beers on me if we ever happen to meet!